# What does Then 1 else 0 mean in a CASE expression used with an aggregate function?

Tags: sql-server

```
SUM(CASE WHEN column1 = 'value1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = 'value2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)..
```

I don't know why I am finding it difficult to understand what exactly is happening in the above statement and what exactly is 'Then 1 else 0' doing here.

Comment: Semi-related, but don't use SUM in this case (if possible), use COUNT http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119945/why-are-multiple-count-faster-than-one-sum-with-case

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `column1` contains the value `value1` then the `CASE` expression will return 1, and `SUM()` will add 1 for that row. If it doesn't, the `CASE` expression will return 0, and it will add 0 for that row. This is a way to count how many rows have `value1` in `column1`, but there are other ways to do this too, e.g. on 2012+:

```
SELECT COUNT(IIF(column1 = 'value1', 'truish', NULL))
```

On earlier versions:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 = 'value1' THEN 'truish' END)
```

(You don't need the `ELSE` here because, unlike `SUM`, `COUNT` ignores `NULL`.)

And I updated the value `1` to be a string to demonstrate that this has nothing to do with boolean.

Comment: Thank you, I must be incredibly dumb, couldn't even understand this. Now that you explained it the way you did, it makes sense. It is finally adding all the 1s for every occurrence of the 'value' in the example I have posted. 

I also wanted to ask, is it the same as :

`CASE WHEN column1 = 'Value1' THEN COUNT(column1) ELSE 0 END AS SomeAliasForCol1Count`

And then using:

`GROUP BY Column1`

Comment: @Ravi No idea, what is that query supposed to return? I don't understand why it would group by the same column you're using inside the aggregate. Why not just `SELECT column1, COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY column1;`?

Comment: Aaron, without that it shows me the error about column not being a part of a GROUP BY clause. That is, if I use Count function in the THEN part of a case statement. You're right about this, I could just use it separately, I was trying to make it appear similar to the multiple SUM functions in the question and see how the same thing would work with COUNT.

Answer (score 3):

That is equivalent to a COUNT IF.  Some people use it to do poor man's unpivot.

SQL evaluates the case statement first, which will return either a 0 or 1.  Then the SUM operation adds up the values.

You can make the CASE statement as complex as you need it to be, even looking up data in other tables.

Comment: So 1 or 0 is like a boolean values, like true or false in that case?

Comment: That's the general effect.  The CASE Statement is the boolean operator and the THEN and ELSE is the return.

Comment: @Ravi No, it's not really a boolean value. `SUM` is either going to count that row or not.

Comment: (Also, just being pedantic about semantics, but in T-SQL, `CASE` is an *expression*, not a *statement* - [more here](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression).)

Comment: I had to look up and read about differences, thank you for pointing this out. I conflate this with something like an IF statement.